# Kaminari gem returns inconsistent records according to sort direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I am using Kaminari to sort joined tables:

```
Hippy.includes(:flowers) # => 535
```

with this code:

```
Hippy.includes(:flowers).page(1).per(50).count # => 50
```

When I sort in ascending order, I get 1 record per page over 11 pages, which I do not expect:

```
Hippy.includes(:flowers).order("flowers.id asc").page(1).per(50).count # => 1
Hippy.includes(:flowers).order("flowers.id asc").page(1).per(50).total_pages # => 11
```

Reversing the order, I get:

```
Hippy.includes(:flowers).order("flowers.id desc").page(1).per(50).count # => 5
Hippy.includes(:flowers).order("hippies.id desc").page(1).per(50).total_pages # => 50
```

Does Kaminari not work when ordering by joined tables? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes you are right, sometime kaminari not work when ordering by joined tables